# Phpmyadmin-error on nginx VPS with Ubuntu 12.04.3 x32

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install phpmyadmin on a VPS LEMP-stack.

I created an info.php, which is perfectly reachable when I call my server's IP in my browser, revealing all relevant php-info, i.e. nginx is running.

However, after installing phpmyadmin, which I try to access via http://192.xxx.xxx.x/phpmyadmin/, I get the following error message:

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

I already installed php5-mysql via `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`, restarted nginx and cleared my browser-cache, but the situation remains.

Could you please advice me what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mysql** and **mysqli** are two different things.

You have to install the mysqli library:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqli
```

Don't forget to also restart the php fpm workers, because that's where the mods get loaded, not in nginx.

```
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

Update:

I was wrong, the php5-mysql package contains the mysql AND the mysqli library.

It must be enough for you to restart the php workers :-)

Comment: The php5-fpm restart worked like a charm. As you already guessed correctly, php5-mysqli is already contained in the php5-mysql library. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I migrated from Apache a few months ago and I have to admit it's really different but it's way faster and better to have PHP detached from the webserver.

Comment: Just working on a larger WordPress-installation and Apache is not scaling well and eats up your memory, that's why the move to nginx. Let's see how that goes...